# What pattern to use for different AngularJS directives in an ng-repeat based on dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a dashboard dynamically from an array of data. The gauges are D3.

I have a selection of different D3 gauges defined in AngularJS directives. On my page I have an ng-repeat iterating over the metrics array.

The question I have is what is the best way to dynamically select the right directive based on an attribute of data in the ng-repeat array?

Is there a way to create a factory pattern where the Directive used is based on an input value from the array? Or is there a way to achieve the result using only Directives by dynamically including other Directives in a Directive?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
<div id="oppChart">
    <div>
        <gh-visualization ng-repeat="item in metrics" val="item[0]"></gh-visualization>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Metrics array (will be dynamic):

```
$scope.list = [
        { 'title': 'XYX','data-type':'', 'query':'SELECT ...' },
        { 'title': 'Revenue', 'data-type':'', 'query':'SELECT ...'  }
      ];
```

D3 Directive based on this - http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html

Answer (score 6):

That would be `ng-switch`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in metrics">
  <div ng-switch on="item.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="optionA">..include </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="optionA">..include </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup I've done this as you describe in your second option.

I created a directive that loads a particular template that then has other directives in them based on a type attribute of the data.

```
    directive("dynamicFormInput", ['$http', '$templateCache', function($http, $templateCache){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //currently need model for map center otherwise can be removed, need to set default in map directive
        scope: {model: '=', section: '='},
        template: '<ng:include src="tpl"></ng:include>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            var sectionToLoad = "";
            switch(scope.section.sectionTypeId)
            {
                case 1:
                    sectionToLoad ='partials/survey/textInput.html';
                  break;
                case 2:
                    sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/selectOneOption.html';
                  break;
                case 3:
                    sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/multiSelectOption.html';
                  break;
                case 4:
                    sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/boolean.html';
                  break;
                case 5:
                    sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/textInput.html';
                  break;
                case 6:
                    if(scope.section.sectionId == 13)
                        sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/addressSelection.html';
                    else if(scope.section.sectionId == 24)
                        sectionToLoad = 'partials/survey/contactForm.html'
                break;
            }
            if(sectionToLoad!="")
            {
                $http.get(sectionToLoad, {cache:$templateCache});
                scope.tpl=sectionToLoad;
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Usage is then like:

```
<accordion
    close-others="true">
    <accordion-group
        ng-repeat="section in sections"
        ng-class="{'isGroundTruthed':section.userId==73}"
        heading="{{section.sectionName}} ({{displaySelection(section)}})">

        <dynamic-form-input
            section="section">
        </dynamic-form-input>

    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

You can ignore the accordion I just happened to use that as my item to repeat so each section would fold up.

**Edit**
Just cleaned up my directive code some.

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution sound more angular-apropriate. So if its just a single directive that is added dynamically

```
app.directive('dynamically',function(){ 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element,attrs){
      var directives = [];
      if (attrs.dynamically.indexOf(' ') > -1){
        directives = attrs.dynamically.split(' ')
      } else {
        directives.push(attrs.dynamically)
      };
      var html = '<ANY ';
      for (var i in directives){
        html += directives[i] + '="true" ';
      };
      html += '></ANY>';
      element.replaceWith(html)
    }
  }
})
```

That's one way to do it.

1) `if (attrs.dynamically.indexOf(' ')` is so that you could implement multiple directives into one instance, seperated by a space char (' ') in this example.

2) I add '="true"' to attribute that i work with by asking `if (attrs.x) {...}`, if attribute x doesn't have a value, it doesn't exist even if stated and located on the DOM.